# Why is a Maybe monad enforced?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am attempting to implement a basic slackbot using the Network.Linklater package:

https://github.com/hlian/linklater

This package defines the following function:

```
slashSimple :: (Command -> IO Text) -> Application
slashSimple f =
  slash (\command _ respond -> f command >>= (respond . responseOf status200))
```

I am attempting to consume this like so:

```
kittensBot :: Command -> IO Text
kittensBot cmd = do
           putStrLn("+ Incoming command: " ++ show cmd)
           return "ok"

main :: IO ()
main = do
     putStrLn ("Listening on port: " ++ show port)
     run port (slashSimple kittensBot)
     where
       port = 3001
```

this produces (at compile time):

```
Main.hs:20:28:
    Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Command’ with ‘Command’
    Expected type: Maybe Command -> IO Text
      Actual type: Command -> IO Text
    In the first argument of ‘slashSimple’, namely ‘kittensBot’
    In the second argument of ‘run’, namely ‘(slashSimple kittensBot)’
```

However the signature of `slashSimple` is `(Command -> IO Text) -> Application`. Shouldn't the signature of `kittensBot` fulfill that? Why doesn't it?

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of the package. I'm sorry about the (ever widening) gap between 4.0 on GitHub and 3.2 on Hackage. I'm still trying to cobble together a good-enough API for the new Web Socket API Slack put out, but maybe I'll just go ahead and publish it soon.

Comment: I uploaded new docs for 4.0.0.0 here: http://hlian.github.io/linklater/hackage/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the definition of `slashSimple` on GitHub master is as you reported, the Hackage version in [linklater-3.2.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linklater-3.2.0.0/docs/Network-Linklater.html#v:slashSimple) is

```
slashSimple :: (Maybe Command -> IO Text) -> Application
```

If you want to use the package on Hackage, you'll need to update kittensBot to something like:

```
kittensBot :: Maybe Command -> IO Text
kittensBot Nothing = ...
kittensBot (Just cmd) = do
       putStrLn("+ Incoming command: " ++ show cmd)
       return "ok"
```

Alternatively, you can download the package from GitHub and manually install it.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. Is it possible to see what code a given version includes?

Comment: The links above show precisely what code is in version 3.2.0.0. If you go to the main Hackage page for `linklater`, you can change the version, and the go to the docs for that version to see the signatures. All versions on Hackage right now have the signature with `Maybe`.

Comment: But what about function bodies rather than signatures?

Comment: For `linklater-3.2.0.0`, there's a link on the right edge of the signature line for the "source". This is only available on recently-built docs. The other option is to go to the top of the documentation page and click the "source" link in the upper right corner.